# Why does "xdg-open" with an URL open two extra empty tabs in Opera?

Tags: linux, browser, opera, xdg

My xdg html default looks like this:

```
$ xdg-mime query default text/html
opera.desktop
```

The `Exec` line in `opera.desktop` looks like this:

```
Exec=opera %U
```

Now, opening a tab in Opera like this:

```
opera "http://google.com"
```

Works perfectly, and opens a single tab, but if I do this:

```
xdg-open "http://google.com"
```

It opens the tab, but additionally opens 2 more tabs with "http://opera/" in the address field. It's basically equivalent to running:

```
opera "http://google.com" opera opera
```

I would expect that the `xdg-open` invocation would work exactly like the `opera` one. How come it doesn't?

---

Here's the whole `opera.desktop` file, unchanged from install:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Opera
GenericName=Web browser
Comment=Fast and secure web browser
TryExec=opera
Exec=opera %U
Terminal=false
Icon=opera
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;application/x-opera-download;
Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=New Window
Exec=opera --new-window
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Desktop Action NewPrivateWindow]
Name=New Private Window
Exec=opera --private
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue with latest version of Opera on Linux. Something must be different on your machine. Have you tried to reset preferences or reinstalling Opera instead?

Comment: Are there hidden characters on the _Exec=opera %U_ line? Are there other opera processes still running? If you change to _Exec=opera -newwindow %U_ does it still show the multiple tabs? How does it fair if you delete the _Actions_ line?

Comment: @strobelight There are no fishy hidden characters. I checked by using `:set list` in vim. I tried adding `-newwindow` and commenting out the Actions line, but nothing changed. I changed the file `/usr/share/applications/opera.desktop`. How can I make sure that's the file that's being used by `xdg-open`?

Comment: @strobelight Ah, I just commented out both the action blocks at the bottom of the file, and that solved it. I assume that's what you meant, and not just the single line starting with Actions. So how come both action blocks are run when I use `xdg-open`? :S

Comment: Well the action blocks shouldn't have been run until you right-clicked on the icon and chose one. If you don't need those actions, and that solved your problem, just leave them out. Something else to try if you want them is preceded the Actions line with a blank line, delete its trailing semicolon, otherwise, you may have to update.